# Convert Date format in a JSON using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a working JOLT except my date part is wrong. I need the date to be in proper format as in the output. Need help to edit my existing jolt

Input JSON :

```json
{
  "Timestamp_UTC": "28-Aug-2023 12:01:00",
  "Control area - Redox 1_Red Sensor": 439.1354,
  "Measure area - Redox 2_Blue Sensor": 455.73474,
  "Voltage": 13.48,
  "Measure area - PH_1_S/N: 2213805": -0.096,
  "Control area - PH_2_S/N: 2213826_CONTROL": 6.171
}
```

Output JSON :

```json
{
  "Date": "28-08-2023 12:01:00",
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "REDOX1",
      "value": 439.1354
    },
    {
      "code": "REDOX2",
      "value": 455.73474
    },
    {
      "code": "PH1",
      "value": -0.096
    },
    {
      "code": "A1-PH2",
      "value": 6.171
    }
  ],
  "stationname": "ftp_device_01"
}
```

Current JOLT :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Timestamp_UTC": "Date",
      "Control area - Redox 1_Red Sensor": "data.REDOX1",
      "Measure area - Redox 2_Blue Sensor": "data.REDOX2",
      "Measure area - PH_1_S/N: 2213805": "data.PH1",
      "Control area - PH_2_S/N: 2213826_CONTROL": "data.A1-PH2"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Date": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2[#2].code",
          "@": "&2[#2].value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "value": [
            "=notNull",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "DtLen": "=size(@(1,Date))",
      "DtDatePart": "=substring(@(1,Date),0,10)",
      "DtDatePartSplit": "=split('/',@(1,DtDatePart))",
      "DtTimePart": "=substring(@(1,Date),10,@(1,DtLen))",
      "DtTimePartTrim": "=trim(@(1,DtTimePart))",
      "Date": "=concat(@(1,DtDatePartSplit[2]),'-',@(1,DtDatePartSplit[1]),'-',@(1,DtDatePartSplit[0]),' ',@(1,DtTimePartTrim))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "Dt*": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "stationname": "ftp_device_01"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've been working on NiFi, you can use expression language along with some more processors rather than manipulating the **`Date`**'s value within a Jolt specification.

You can add

- **GetFile** processor : Assuming the input JSON value is in a file
- **SplitJSON** processor : To individually get each JSON value as attributes by using

  **`JsonPath Expression`** is **`$.*`**
- **EvaluateJSONPath** processor : To create an attribute called `Timestamp_UTC` by adding a property

  with name **`Timestamp_UTC`** vs. with value **`$.Timestamp_UTC`** as

  the **`Destination`** property's value is **`flowfile-attribute`**
- **UpdateAttribute** processor : To perform datetime conversion by adding a new

  property **`Timestamp_UTC`** with value

  **`${Timestamp_UTC:toDate('dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'):format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}`**
- **JoltTransformJSON** processor with the following specification :

  ```json
  [
    {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "Timestamp_UTC": "Date",
        "*": "data.&" // all elements other than "Timestamp_UTC" 
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "Date": "&",
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&2[#2].code",
            "@": "&2[#2].value"
          }
        },
        "#ftp_device_01": "stationname" // to add a fixed valued attribute
      }
    },
    {
      "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
      "spec": {
        "Date": "${Timestamp_UTC}",
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "value": [
              "=notNull",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  ```

The following image shows the complete NiFi flow :

[image]

Yet, you can do all in a **JoltTransformJSON** processor as an alternative but need to hardcode all the month numbers vs. their abbreviated literals along with the following transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Timestamp_UTC": "Date",
      "*": "data.&" // all elements other than "Timestamp_UTC" 
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Date": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2[#2].code",
          "@": "&2[#2].value"
        }
      },
      "#ftp_device_01": "stationname" // to add a fixed valued attribute
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Date": "=split('-',@(1,&))",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "value": [
            "=notNull",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Date": {
        "1": {
          "Jan": { "#01": "&3" },
          "Feb": { "#02": "&3" },
          "Mar": { "#03": "&3" },
          "Apr": { "#04": "&3" },
          "May": { "#05": "&3" },
          "Jun": { "#06": "&3" },
          "Jul": { "#07": "&3" },
          "Aug": { "#08": "&3" },
          "Sep": { "#09": "&3" },
          "Oct": { "#10": "&3" },
          "Nov": { "#11": "&3" },
          "Dec": { "#12": "&3" }
        },
        "*": "&1"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Date": "=join('-',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do in JOLT (just the date conversion), because the original input file is a bit different and we are doing some changes, it would be very convenient to this in JOLT rather than including new steps within the pipeline